# Powershell - Remove last comma in foreach

Tags: json, powershell, zabbix

I am rather new to powershell scripting and need help with my script below. I need to remove the last comma "," from the result below. This is JSON format that I need to be able to use this info for Zabbix monitoring of Hyper-V VMs.

script:

```
    $colItems = Get-VM

write-host "{"
write-host " `"data`":["
write-host

foreach ($objItem in $colItems) {
    $line =  " { `"{#VMNAME}`":`"" + $objItem.Name + "`" , `"{#VMSTATE}`":`"" + $objItem.State + "`" },"
    write-host $line
}

write-host
write-host " ]"
write-host "}"
write-host
```

Here is the result from this:

```
{ 
 "data":[

 { "{#VMNAME}":"cp01" , "{#VMSTATE}":"Off" },
 { "{#VMNAME}":"dc01" , "{#VMSTATE}":"Running" },
 { "{#VMNAME}":"ex01" , "{#VMSTATE}":"Off" },
 { "{#VMNAME}":"fc01" , "{#VMSTATE}":"Running" },
 { "{#VMNAME}":"rdg01" , "{#VMSTATE}":"Running" },
 { "{#VMNAME}":"Windows 2012R2 G2 Template" , "{#VMSTATE}":"Off" }, <--- THIS I WANT TO REMOVE

 ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON is not a flat string, never try to build it by concatenating flat strings and hoping that it will come out all-right in the end.

JSON is a *serialized data structure*, treat it as such. Make a data structure and serialize it.

In your case that data structure should be an object (i.e. hashtable) that contains the key `data`, which in turn contains an array of objects. That's easy enough to do.

```
$result = @{}
$result.data = @()

foreach ($vm in Get-VM) {
    $result.data += @{
        "{#VMNAME}" = $vm.Name;
        "{#VMSTATE}" = $vm.State;
    }
}

$result | ConvertTo-Json
```

Done.

---

Alternative notation, using the `foreach` shorthand `%`, saving the temp variables and a few lines:

```
@{
    "data" = Get-VM | % { 
        @{
            "{#VMNAME}" = $_.Name;
            "{#VMSTATE}" = $_.State;
        }
    }
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: @elimat Have another look at my answer, I've improved it a bit further.

Comment: I see, very nice. Thank you. I will keep this in mind.